# Docker / Postgres - Trying to run 2 databases and 2 apis, cannot connect

Tags: postgresql, docker, rest, go, docker-compose

I am trying to use my docker-compose file to run 2 instances of both my database, and my rest api, so that I can run tests on a test instance of the database.

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.2-alpine
    container_name: "db-prod"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - fullstack
    volumes:
      - database_postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  db_test:
    image: postgres:13.2-alpine
    container_name: "db-test"
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      - fullstack-test
    volumes:
      - database_postgres_test:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  api:
    build: .
    container_name: "rest-api"
    environment:
      DB_USERNAME: "postgres"
      DB_PASSWORD: "password"
      DB_HOST: "db-prod"
      DB_TABLE: "postgres"
      DB_DB: "postgres"
      DB_PORT: "5432"

    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - fullstack
  
  api_test:
    build: .
    container_name: "rest-api-test"
    environment:
      DB_USERNAME: "postgres"
      DB_PASSWORD: "password"
      DB_HOST: "db-test"
      DB_TABLE: "postgres"
      DB_DB: "postgres"
      DB_PORT: "5433"

    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db_test
    networks:
      - fullstack-test

volumes:
  database_postgres: 
  database_postgres_test: 

networks:
  fullstack:
    driver: bridge
  fullstack-test:
    driver: bridge
```

When i run this, my prod database starts, and my regular API connects to it fine.

My test DB also starts, and I can connect to it using
`psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 5433`
however my test rest API wi

`dial tcp 192.168.112.2:5433: connect: connection refused`

The goal is to set up my go tests to run on the test DB and just clear after each test as needed, and not affect the prod db.

I am not sure if I am going about this the right way - perhaps there is a better construct for this - and if so please correct me. But regardless, I do not understand why im getting this error?

I dont get why one connection works well and the other fails?

Edit: Also interesting, i just noticed if i change the api_test container to use:

`DB_HOST: "host.docker.internal"`

it works. But i still dont understand why one can use a container name and the other cannot? And i cant leave it this way as it needs to work on a mac as well, and host.docker.internal doesnt work on my mac (hence why the first one was changed to the container name)

Comment: `ports: "5433:5432"` exposes the containers port `5432` on the host as port `5433`. This mapping is only relevant when you are connecting via the host (i.e. your `psql` test or `host.docker.internal`). When accessing `db_test` directly via the `fullstack-test` network use port `5432`.

Comment: I changed it and this worked but as soon as I tried to refactor things and make a docker-compose.test.yml it all fell apart. Now it just complains that the user password doesnt match, even though i can psql into it with the password perfectly fine.

Comment: "I tried to refactor things" - sorry can't really help without the updated details. You are probably not connecting to the database you think you are...